# BigQuery scheduling: Error code 3 : reauth related error

Tags: google-bigquery

I have scheduled queries on BigQuery.

They have failed since last Thursday.

I got the error below on the Run Detail section

```
Error code 3 : reauth related error (invalid_rapt)
```

[image]

Cannot find the error code on Troubleshooting on BigQuery document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are posting is being treated in [this public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142772110). It appears that this issue is related with the Google Cloud authentication permissions. Recently,  the Cloud ReAuth policy was introduced in order to improve the [user authentication](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/). The Cloud ReAuth policy includes an additional token that must be provided in each API request. After 20 hours, the token will expire and the user must reauthenticate in order to use GCP APIs, use `gcloud` or access to the Google Cloud Platform UI.

Updating the user credentials can be employed as a workaround when BigQuery raises the error `Error code 3 : reauth related error (invalid_rapt)` for a particular query. There are two ways this can be done:

1 - From the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/) following the instructions of the [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) command [`gcloud auth application-default login`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login).

2 - From the [BigQuery web UI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui). Inside the  “Scheduled query details” you will find the “MORE” options on the right side. By clicking on “MORE” -> “Update credentials” the user credentials will be updated for this particular query.