# What does the error code 'Error code 3 : Bad Request' mean in terms of a failing scheduled query in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a scheduled query (update_table_name) that is supposed to run daily but has failed each day beginning 11/14. No prior issues. I can't find any documentation on this error code that would give me a clue how to fix. Our data engineer's last day was 11/13 and I don't think that is a coincidence but then again, all other scheduled queries are running as expected and his account has not yet been removed. Does anyone know what might be going on or have a suggestion?

Comment: Please see a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889340/bigquery-scheduling-error-code-3-reauth-related-error

Comment: @rtenha could you please post this as an answer so that it can be marked as the correct solution? Thank you.

Comment: No need. It isn't really a solution and the question should probably be flagged as a duplicate.